# Compare text in dataframe with words in dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, matching, text-classification

I constructed the dictionary (MYdict) which outputs:

```
{'MATCH': ['actor', 'addicted', 'addiction', 'affected', 'alli', 'angel', 'ani', 'apartment', 'astrology', 'avoiding', 'beach', 'being', 'belong', 'bipolar', 'bitter', 'bold', 'bond', 'bottle', 'brave', 'breath', 'burning', 'bus', 'camera', 'channel', 'chaotic', 'choosing', 'cloud', 'commit', 'complain', 'confess', 'confusion', 'cooky', 'courage', 'credit', 'crisis', 'customer', 'cycle', 'cynical', 'darkness', 'david', 'daydream', 'daydreaming', 'depressing', 'dragon', 'dreamer', 'dreaming', 'edge', 'elementary', 'encounter', 'europe', 'evening', 'expressed', 'feature', 'flower', 'flying', 'focusing', 'fool', 'fresh', 'fucked', 'gentle', 'giant', 'goodness', 'gorgeous', 'graduate', 'granted', 'grateful', 'growth', 'guilt', 'happyi', 'heaven', 'highschool', 'hint', 'idealism', 'idealist', 'idealistic', 'ignoring', 'imaginary', 'imagining', 'incredible', 'infpi', 'innocent', 'inspiration', .... ]}
```

Also I have a dataframe of posts as follows:

```
|    | posts                                             |
| -- | ------------------------------------------------- |
| 1  | [tend, build, collection, thing, desktop, freq... |
| 2  | [question, distinction, dependant, perception,... |
| 3  | [position, person, due, reason, unfortunately,... |
| 4  | [interested, lazy, research, timeconsuming, we... |
| ...| ...                                               |
| 167| [generally, experience, post, trauma, similar,... |
```

Now I want to use this dictionary to classify the text data. (if posts mention at least one word in the dictionary, return 1)

Expected outputs:

```
|     | posts                                            | MATCH |
| --- | ------------------------------------------------ | ----- |
| 1   | [tend, build, collection, thing, desktop, freq...|0      |
| 2   | [question, distinction, dependant, perception,...|1      |
| 3   | [position, person, due, reason, unfortunately,...|1      |
| 4   | [interested, lazy, research, timeconsuming, we...|0      |
| ... | ...                                              |...    |
| 167 | [generally, experience, post, trauma, similar,...|1      |
```

```
def matches(x):
    # x == string
    for i in dic_INFP.values():
        #i == list
        if x in i:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

X_test_clean["INFP"] = X_test_clean["posts"].apply(lambda x: matches(x))
```

I tried this but it returns 0 for all rows. Tell me how to solve this problem, please ;(

Comment: You have no reference to `MYdict` in the code.

Comment: Why do you keep removing the code formatting of the dictionary every time you edit?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'x' is a list of strings. `apply` loops the dataframe one cell at a time. And in each of the cell, you have a list of strings. In order to properly perform matching on the list items of each cell, you have to loop the `x`.

Also, you have to move the `return 0` out of the for loop, because you don't want the loop to stop on the first word that does not match. `return 0` should only happen after looping through all the words.

#### Here is the code for you (tested)

```py
import pandas as pd

dic_INFP = {'MATCH': ['actor', 'addicted', 'addiction', 'affected', 'alli'], 'SOMEHSD': ['angel', 'ani', 'apartment', 'astrology', 'avoiding', 'beach', 'being', 'belong']}

X_test_clean = pd.DataFrame({
        'posts': [['tend', 'build', 'collection', 'thing', 'desktop'], ['question', 'distinction', 'dependant'], ['position', 'person', 'addicted']],
})

def matches(x):
    # x == list <------ it is a list
    for i in dic_INFP.values():
        #i == list
        for e in x:
            if e in i:
                return 1
    return 0

X_test_clean["INFP"] = X_test_clean["posts"].apply(lambda x: matches(x))

print(X_test_clean)
```

#### Output:

```
                                       posts  INFP
0  [tend, build, collection, thing, desktop]     0
1         [question, distinction, dependant]     0
2               [position, person, addicted]     1
```